# Use of verify() method with and without times(1) parameter

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I couldn't find any practical difference between these two usages. Just to avoid future complications, could it possibly cause an issue selecting randomly any one of them?

1. `verify(mockObj).foo();`
2. `verify(mockObj, times(1)).foo();`

If they are exactly the same, which one can be assumed as the best practice?

Comment: good question. what happens if you use `verify(mock).foo();` and `foo` gets called multiple times? maybe `times(1)` makes sure it fails if `foo` gets called more than once.

Comment: The samples I provided above, no:1 and no:2 both fail in case of calls more than once. Turns out they are indeed equivalent as mentioned in Javadoc @namenotfound

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are equivalent. From the Javadoc of [`Mockito#verify(T)`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.3.3/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verify-T-):

> Verifies certain behavior **happened once.**
>
> Alias to `verify(mock, times(1))` E.g:
>
> ```java
> verify(mock).someMethod("some arg");
> ```
>
> Above is equivalent to:
>
> ```java
> verify(mock, times(1)).someMethod("some arg");
> ```
>
> *[...]*

Which is considered better than the other is subjective. The first option (no `times(1)`) is shorter but the second option (with `times(1)`) makes the code's intentions explicit. The second option also allows you to [specify a description](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.3.3/org/mockito/verification/VerificationMode.html#description-java.lang.String-) for if and when the verification fails.

Use whichever you and your team believe will be the most readable. In particular, make sure you'll understand the code when coming back to it at some point in the future.